# VIsual Studio 2012 not firing PostBuild event?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have class library project for which I would like to create a `nuget` package.

So i first created a `nuspec` file by running the following in the project folder:

```
'nuget spec'
```

Then I added the following in my project file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Message Text="### AfterBuild ###" Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="nuget pack MyProjectNameHere.csproj -Prop Platform=AnyCPU"></Exec>
</Target>
```

When I build the project from with VS, the package is not built and the message is not shown.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your output window show anything?

Comment: @JBrooks Just that project was successfully built.

Comment: Are you running the command with the quotes? If so, try running it without them. (I don't know if this will change anything, but it might)